# jQuery not changing the background

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html code is:

```
<ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-one" ><span class="righttab activeright">&nbsp;</span><span class="lefttab activeleft">&nbsp;</span><a href="#featured" class="current">Featured</a></li>
        <li class="nav-two" ><span class="righttab" id="rightnav2">&nbsp;</span><span class="lefttab" id="leftnav2">&nbsp;</span><a href="#core" >Core</a></li>
        <li class="nav-three" ><span class="righttab" id="rightnav3">&nbsp;</span><span class="lefttab" id="leftnav3">&nbsp;</span><a href="#jquerytuts" >jQuery</a></li>
        <li class="nav-four last" ><span class="righttab" id="rightnav4">&nbsp;</span><span class="lefttab" id="leftnav4">&nbsp;</span><a href="#classics" >Classics</a></li>
</ul>
```

and my jQuery code is:

```
    jQuery(".nav-two").hover(function() { 
      $('#rightnav2').css("background-image", "url(/skin/frontend/unleaded/worldeffect/images/tabover1-right.jpg)");  
      $('#leftnav2').css("background-image", "url(/skin/frontend/unleaded/worldeffect/images/tabover1-left.jpg)"); 
    });
```

This is a supposed to change the background image when I rollover with my mouse. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When you pass a single function to `.hover()` that code is executed on `mouseenter` **and** `mouseleave`. That's probably not what you want to happen in this case. Also, are you sure that the URLs are correct?

Comment: Yes the function is firing and the urls are correct. Nothing is changing on mousenter or mouseleave

Comment: what are the width and height of the images?

Comment: The problem was that I can't use $ as it conflicts and I needed to replace it with jQuery for it to work. So I am going to award to Nick for show how to fully use the hover function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common usage of `.hover` is to pass two functions to it: the first for mouse enter and the second for mouse leave. If you pass just one function, as you have there, then it is executed for both events, and your handler should interrogate the Event object to decide what to do. So, if your intention was to have the background image change when you mouse over and then revert when you mouse out, then you should provide a second function setting the background image to `''`.

Comment: How would I define two functions for hover?

Comment: `.hover(function () { /* your mouse over function */ }, function () { /* your mouse out function */ })`. Also, there is some online documentation you know ;) http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover1

Answer (score 0):

```
   jQuery(".nav-two").hover(function() { 
      $('#rightnav2').css("backgroundImage", "url(/skin/frontend/unleaded/worldeffect/images/tabover1-right.jpg)");  
      $('#leftnav2').css("backgroundImage", "url(/skin/frontend/unleaded/worldeffect/images/tabover1-left.jpg)"); 
    });
```

You may need to replace all '-' in css attributes with the camel case equivalent.

ie. background-image becomes backgroundImage

Comment: jQuery normalises this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a CSS class for each background

```
$(".nav-two").bind({
    mouseenter: function(){
       $('#leftnav2').addClass('hover1');
       $('#rightnav2').addClass('hover2');
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
       $('#leftnav2').removeClass('hover1');
       $('#rightnav2').removeClass('hover2');
    },
});
```

or

```
$(".nav-two").hover(
  function () {
           $('#leftnav2').addClass('hover1');
           $('#rightnav2').addClass('hover2');
  },
  function () {
           $('#leftnav2').removeClass('hover1');
           $('#rightnav2').removeClass('hover2');
  }
);
```